# weird behaviour when $_POST-ing text which includes "Location:"

Tags: php

I have made a simple html+php solution for uploading events. When in the description of the event, there is the following text:
`blabla ... Location: blabla ...` the script fails with:
`Forbidden You don't have permission to access /pathto/adminAddEvent.php on this server.` At all other times it works.

html:

```
        <form id="formUploadFile" method="post" action="adminAddEvent.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="iframeUploadFile">
            <iframe id="iframeUploadFile" onload="jsOnUploadCompletion();" name="iframeUploadFile" src="" style="width: 1px; height: 1px; display: none;"></iframe>
            <table border=1>
                <tr><td>Event Start Date</td></tr>
                <tr><td><input name="EventStartDate" id="EventStartDate" type="date"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Event End Date</td></tr>
                <tr><td><input name="EventEndDate" id="EventEndDate" type="date"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Event Time</td></tr>
                <tr><td><input name="EventTime" id="EventTime" type="text"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Language</td></tr>
                <tr><td>
                        <select name="EventLanguage" id="EventLanguage" style="width: 200px;">
                            <option value="GR">Greek</option>
                            <option value="EN">English</option>
                        </select>
                </td></tr>
                <tr><td>Description</td></tr>
                <tr><td><textarea name="EventDescription" id="EventDescription" style="width: 300px;"></textarea></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Facebook Link</td></tr>
                <tr><td><input name="EventFBLink" id="EventFBLink" type="text" maxlength="1024" size="50"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Image</td></tr>
                <tr><td><input type="file" name="inputUploadFile" id="inputUploadFile" onchange="jsOnFileSelected()"/></td></tr>
                <tr><td>
                    <button id="btnUpload" type="submit" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px;">Add event</button>
                </td></tr>
            </table>
        </form>
```

adminAddEvent.php:

```
require_once("con_db.php");

date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Athens");

if ( isset($_POST['EventStartDate']) && isset($_POST['EventEndDate']) && isset($_POST['EventDescription']) ) {
    $EventStartDate = trim($_POST['EventStartDate']);
    $EventEndDate = trim($_POST['EventEndDate']);
    $EventTime = trim($_POST['EventTime']);
    $EventLanguage = trim($_POST['EventLanguage']);
    $EventDescription = trim($_POST['EventDescription']);
    $EventFBLink = "";
    if (isset($_POST['EventFBLink'])) {
        $EventFBLink = trim($_POST['EventFBLink']);
    }
    if (strlen($EventStartDate) > 0 && strlen($EventEndDate) > 0 && strlen($EventTime) > 0 && strlen($EventLanguage) > 0 && strlen($EventDescription) > 0) {
        $authuser_PRST = $PDOCONN->prepare("INSERT INTO tblevents (EventStartDate, EventEndDate, EventTime, EventDescription, EventFBLink, EventLanguage) VALUES(:EventStartDate, :EventEndDate, :EventTime, :EventDescription, :EventFBLink, :EventLanguage)");
        $authuser_PRST->bindValue(":EventStartDate", $EventStartDate);
        $authuser_PRST->bindValue(":EventEndDate", $EventEndDate);
        $authuser_PRST->bindValue(":EventTime", $EventTime);
        $authuser_PRST->bindValue(":EventDescription", $EventDescription);
        $authuser_PRST->bindValue(":EventFBLink", $EventFBLink);
        $authuser_PRST->bindValue(":EventLanguage", $EventLanguage);
        $authuser_PRST->execute() or die($PDOCONN->errorInfo());
        
        $lastInsertedID = $PDOCONN->lastInsertID();
        
        $folder = "../events/" . $lastInsertedID;
        if (!file_exists($folder)) {
            mkdir($folder, 0777, true);
        }
        $target_dir = $folder . "/";
        
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["inputUploadFile"]["name"]);
        //$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["inputUploadFile"]["name"]);
        $uploadOk = 1;

        if (file_exists($target_file)) {
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }

        if ($_FILES["inputUploadFile"]["error"] > 0) {
            $strRes =  "Error: " . $_FILES["inputUploadFile"]["error"] . "<br>";
        } else {
            if ($uploadOk == 0) {
                $strRes =  "Error: the file already exists";
            } else {
                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["inputUploadFile"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
                    $authuser_PRST = $PDOCONN->prepare("UPDATE tblevents SET EventImage = :EventImage WHERE id = :id");
                    $authuser_PRST->bindValue(":EventImage", $target_file);
                    $authuser_PRST->bindValue(":id", $lastInsertedID);
                    $authuser_PRST->execute() or die($PDOCONN->errorInfo());
                    $strRes = "event addedd successfully";
                } else {
                    $strRes =  "Error: something's wrong with saving file";
                }
            }
        }

        echo $strRes;
    } else {
        echo "Error: Wrong Parameter Length";
    }
} else {
    echo "Error: Missing Parameter";
}
```

So, I'm not sure why this is happening and what I'm doing wrong, I know "Location: " has a specific meaning in PHP, but I don't see why should it be parsed like this.
php version is: 7.0.33

Thank you advance.

EDIT:
Apparently it's not a PHP problem, but a modsecurity filter issue, from error_log:

```
[Mon Jul 26 12:09:54.353453 2021] [:error] [pid 12975:tid 140555522520832] [client 255.255.255.255:60940] [client 255.255.255.255] ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Pattern match "[\\\\r\\\\n]\\\\W*?(?:content-(type|length)|set-cookie|location):" at MATCHED_VAR. [file "/etc/httpd/conf/modsecurity.d/rules/comodo_free/12_HTTP_Protocol.conf"] [line "148"] [id "211080"] [rev "2"] [msg "COMODO WAF: HTTP Response Splitting Attack||www.myexample.com|F|2"] [data "Matched Data: location found within MATCHED_VAR: dfdsfds\\x0d\\x0alocation: dffds\\x0d\\x0asadfsdfsd"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [tag "CWAF"] [tag "Protocol"] [hostname "www.myexample.com"] [uri "/myadminfolder/adminAddEvent.php"] [unique_id "YP574tdofF2tOu4ovUS1IQAAAGY"], referer: https://www.myexample.com/myadminfolder/addevent.php
```

Comment: Have you tried changing permission of the file? Try giving 755 Or 775 permission to the adminAddEvent.php

Comment: why should I do that? the problem ONLY occurs when in the EventDescription field, there is a specific text.

Comment: Could you please update your question and show in which line exactly the error occurs?

Comment: @wayneOS I added a try catch but no exception is thrown. I even artificially threw an exception with `throw new Exception("test exception");` in the beginning of the script but it doesn't get thrown. I don't know why.

Comment: @MirrorMirror but you obviously got the error `Forbidden You don't have permission to access /pathto/adminAddEvent.php on this server.`. So there were surely a line-number given.

Comment: @wayneOS I edited my post, it seems it's not a php issue, but a mod_security one

Comment: @MirrorMirror ;) well that makes a lot more sense. Could you just use something other than `Location:` in your post-data? For example `Loc:`

Comment: @wayneOS I elected to disable CWAF filter. Doesn't make sense to me to not be able to allow specific string in user provided content. I don't know how this would be potentially be dangerous in this particular case in the way that it's handled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by mod_security COMODO WAF filter. I disabled it.